# How do I automatically split huxtables across multiple pages?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, huxtable

**Goal:**
In the Shiny app I'm working on, the users can upload a `.csv` file, which is converted to a huxtable, gets formatted and can finally be downloaded as a `.pdf`. Since the users can upload their own dataset, I don't know in advance how many rows it will contain and if the table will need to be split across multiple pages. Therefore, it would be handy if the table would be **automatically** split if it is longer than one page in the `.pdf` file. I know I could achieve this with other packages like `flextable`, but `flextable` does not support padding when rendered to pdf.

**Problem:**
If the table becomes too long, it will be pushed to the next page and anything longer than the page will not be displayed.
I know the function `split_across()`, but I could not solve my problem with it.
 If I set a fixed value for example a split after every twentieth row and then a cell contains a lot of text and the text is wrapped and thus takes more space, I have the same problem again.

**Reprex:**

````
---
output: 
  pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)

library(huxtable)
```

# Title Text

```{r}
faithful[1, 1] <- paste0(
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod ",
  "tempor incididunt ut, labore et dolore magna aliqua."
)

as_hux(faithful) |>
  set_wrap(everywhere, everywhere, TRUE) |>
  set_width(0.8)
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea with `split_across` is actually the right approach. You need to:

1. Split your table in multiple with `split_across`.
2. This will return a `list`(!) of `huxtables`.
3. You can use `to_latex` to render them.
4. As you are rendering them by hand, you need to make sure that the required `LaTeX` packages are added.
5. Some syntactic sugar to make sure the labels are set properly.

````
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    extra_dependencies: ["array","adjustbox","threeparttable","tabularx","colortbl","hhline","calc"]
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)

library(huxtable)
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)
```

# Title Text

```{r, results = "asis"}
faithful[1, 1] <- paste0(
  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod ",
  "tempor incididunt ut, labore et dolore magna aliqua."
)
## just to see if all rows are added
faithful <- cbind(row_nr = 1:nrow(faithful), faithful) 

rows_first_page <- 20L
max_rows_per_page <- 23L

hux_list <- as_hux(faithful) %>%
  set_wrap(everywhere, everywhere, TRUE) %>%
  set_width(0.8) %>% 
  split_across(., after = seq(rows_first_page , nrow(.), by = max_rows_per_page))


hux_lat <- imap_chr(hux_list, 
                    ~ .x %>% 
                      set_label(
                        paste0("tab:", 
                               knitr::opts_current$get("label"), "-", .y)) %>% 
                      to_latex()) %>% 
  paste(collapse = "\n\n")

cat(hux_lat)
```
````

Comment: Your solution works fine for the reprex. But suppose we have wrapped text in another cell e.g. `faithful[2, 1] <- paste0("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod ", "tempor incididunt ut, labore et dolore magna aliqua.")`, then the method will fail again. Since I'm dealing with user-uploaded files, I don't know in advance how much content each cell has.

Comment: Well, you need to make some assumptions of how many rows fit on one page. You can use some calculation based on row content and your design. So for example, you could find out how many rows (single lines) would fix at most on one page and then count how many lines (not rows) are there. But as the wrapping is done by `hux` and in turn depends (I guess) on the amount of columns, it may be difficult to predict accurately.

Comment: Ok, then I guess this problem is not solvable without making some assumptions. But anyway thanks for the help.